# How to prove that this function is differentiable?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

> Let $$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}(x^2+y^2) \sin\left(\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}\right)&\text{if}\;x^2+y^2 \neq 0\\\\0&\text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$
>
> Prove that $f$ is differentiable

Could anyone give me a hint please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Prove that$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{f(x,y)-f(0,0)}{\lVert(x,y)\rVert}=0.$$

Comment: what about not (0,0)?

Comment: why we do this?

Comment: Outside $(0,0)$, your function can be expressed from differentiable functions using arithmetic operations and composition. Therefore, it is differentiable there.

Comment: We do this in order to prove that $f'(0,0)$ is the null function.

Comment: why we want to prove this?

Comment: I did so because I thought you wanted to prove that $f$ is differentiable. Am I wrong?

Comment: no you are correct but I am asking about the definition of differentiability you used

Comment: The function $f$ is differentiable at $(a,b)$ if there is a linear map $L\colon\mathbb{R}^2\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ such that$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(a,b)}\frac{\lVert f(x,y)-f(a,b)-L(x-a,y-b)\rVert}{\lVert(x,y)-(a,b)\rVert}=0.$$

Comment: what is L remainder?

Comment: It is $f'(a,b)$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Use the polar coordinates
$$x = r \cos\theta \\ y = r \sin \theta$$

and simplify $f(x,y) \to f(r, \theta)$.